Can a binary tree be generated from Union-Find using union-by-rank?
I'm trying to determine if the following claims are true or false:
Claim 1
When disjoint Union-Find is implemented using up-trees and union-by-rank, and initially 
there was a set of 5 single nodes. After several union operations it is possible that a 
single tree contains all nodes, and the resulting tree is a binary tree. 
Claim 2
When disjoint Union-Find is implemented using up-trees and union-by-rank, and initially 
there was a set of 6 single nodes. After several union operations a single tree contains 
all nodes. The resulting tree might be a binary tree.
I wrote a really long proof for Claim 1 from which I concluded that the claim is wrong.
I saw that the same argument can be applied for the Claim 2, which I concluded also wrong.
Basically, I claim that because the use of rank in the Union operation, it is guaranteed that a tree with 3 children will be generated.
Is Claim 1 and Claim 2 are false ?

Do you have a specific question?  "Will like to get some opinion on that." is too vague and open-ended to be a good fit for this platform.  Our goal is to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others, in the form of high-quality questions and answers... so we need questions to be focused and clear.

@D.W. You right. I didn't want to write "Is claim 1 and 2 are false" because I didn't provide a detail proof (mainly because it's very long and I think the last sentence summarized it in a decent way). I know that I need to show effort in what I wrote, so this is way I choose this words.  I edited the question.

Thanks for the clarification.  Now it becomes clear that you are asking two questions.  The usual rule here is to please ask only one question per post.  Also, I suggest you tell us where you ran across those claims (can you credit the source where you encountered them?).

I'm learning this data structure and this arrows naturally.
I tried to "test" my claims here https://kubokovac.eu/gnarley-trees/UnionFind.html and it led me to wrote what I wrote. I don't want to waste unnecessary time from the reader of the post, so I gave an highlight of the proof I wrote.
